# In flutter how to return true when data change?

Tags: flutter

I tried to animate every time I have my double change.

ex   my double change to 1.562  I search to return true and come back to false
next my double passe to 1.563  I search to return true and come back to false
etc...

like that I could launch my animation for every change of my counter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to listen to a sequence of events.
https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

You can add events to a StreamController with the `_updateDouble` from the place in your app where you get your new `double` value.

```
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
    final StreamController<double> myDoubleStreamController = StreamController();
    StreamSubscription _subscription;

    void initState() {
        _subscription = myDoubleStreamController.stream.listen((double myDouble){
            // Start animation
        });
    }

    void dispose() {
        _subscription.cancel();
    }

    void _updateDouble(double newDouble){
        myDoubleStreamController.sink.add(newDouble);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I don't succes, my double comes from an inherited widget. In my example I can't write like this :stream.listen((double state.myDouble)